# Apostrophe doesn't get translated properly when placed in a resource bundle

Tags: java, resourcebundle

Apostrophe doesn't get translated properly when placed in a resource bundle.

```
key = {0}'s brush is {1} centimeters tall

(e.g. Sam's brush is 4 centimeters tall)
```

The apostrophe gets missed if I format the above key from a `java.util.ResourceBundle` What could be the problem here?

Comment: +1 I ran into this problem myself and wrote a small blog post about it. Maybe it can provide additional information for people running into this "feature": http://www.mscharhag.com/2013/10/single-quote-escaping-in-java-resource.html

Answer (score 143, accepted):

You should escape the single quote as

```
key = {0}''s brush is {1} centimeters tall
```

Comment: Nice answer. This has solved my issue with single quotes. Thanks :) +1

Comment: This has solved my issue too after spending over one hour with other solutions

Comment: This is one of those things I'm not going to tell anyone at work that I googled. Thank you.

Answer (score 37):

I strongly belive that the problem is not the ressource bundle but the [MessageFormater](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) you use to print the message:

[From MessageFormater java doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html):

> Within a String, '' (*two single quotes* ) represents a
>   single quote. A QuotedString can
>   contain arbitrary characters except
>   single quotes; the surrounding single
>   quotes are removed. An UnquotedString
>   can contain arbitrary characters
>   except single quotes and left curly
>   brackets. Thus, a string that should
>   result in the formatted message
>   '{0}' can be written as '''{'0}''
>   or '''{0}'''.

So you need to write:

```
{0}''s brush is {1} centimeters tall
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding to @Ralph's answer:
You will realize that this is a `MessageFormat` thing when you have a text like

```
text1=It's too late
```

versus

```
text2={0}''s too late
```

`text1` would probably not run through a MessageFormater (e.g. spring has different code paths if arguments are passed or not), whereas `text2` would.
So if you used two single quotes in `text1`, they may / will display as such. So you'll need to check if any arguments get formatted in or not and use one or two single quotes accordingly.

Comment: This is a nice information, thank you. 
Also, it is a very dumb situation.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html)

> Within a String, "''" represents a
>   single quote. A QuotedString can
>   contain arbitrary characters except
>   single quotes; the surrounding single
>   quotes are removed. An UnquotedString
>   can contain arbitrary characters
>   except single quotes and left curly
>   brackets. Thus, a string that should
>   result in the formatted message
>   "'{0}'" can be written as "'''{'0}''"
>   or "'''{0}'''".

Comment: I have issue when use double quote with a message without {} or no args. When that  MessageFormat will not process and return raw message.

You need to turn on option **alwaysUseMessageFormat** to MessageFormat always processes.

Answer (score 6):

If you are completely stuck, as I was (none of the above worked), you can replace the apostrophe sign with its Unicode: \u0027. Remember you are always allowed to use UTF symbol in your properties file.

Answer (score 5):

You need to double single quote i.e. {0}''s brush is {1} centimeters tall

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Properties Editor plugin (for Eclipse)

http://propedit.sourceforge.jp/index_en.html

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that has Android problems in the string.xml, use \'\' instead of single quote.